# it is possible to use Servermanager.exe on window 7

Tags: server, exchange-server, powershell-2.0

I want to install Microsoft Exchange Server in Windows 7, but it's having some prerequisites.

We need to execute the following command

```
ServerManagerCmd -i RSAT-ADDS
ServerManagerCmd -i PowerShell
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Server
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-ISAPI-Ext
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Metabase
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Basic-Auth
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Digest-Auth
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Windows-Auth
ServerManagerCmd -i Web-Dyn-Compression
```

How can I enable the Servermanager command in Windows 7?

Answer (score 0):

No, this command is only available on Windows Server 2008 and Windows Server 2008 R2.

Servermanagercmd.exe has been deprecated, and is not available in Windows Server 2012, nor is it available on desktop versions of Windows.

([Source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee344834.aspx))

Comment: How  can i install window server over window 7.Can i install microsoft exchange server over Window 7. Please help.